# Executing a transaction from a Gnosis Safe using another address once signers of the safe have signed the transaction

Tags: gnosis, gnosis-safe

I am using a delegate signer for my Gnosis Safe Multisig to just propose transactions to the front interface programatically, and I wanted to know if it was possible to let this delegate signer execute transaction once it has been signed by the signers of the multisig.

It could be a game changer greatly helping us automate a lot of stuff in our processes.

The solution would be to query Gnosis API to fetch signatures from addresses which have already signed but I don't know if this is actually feasible to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is feasible.

The idea of the Safe transaction service is to provide this information so that it can be used in any ways. As long as **all owners** have submitted their signatures it is possible to use any way to execute it. This could include relayers or dedicated execution keys.

The Safe web interface will start allowing also non-owners to execute transactions (see https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/1811).

In the past this was also used by the Gnosis Safe Relay Service https://github.com/gnosis/safe-relay-service (deprecated)